# Cofinality of a limit ordinal is equal to the cofinality of a given normal operation - Proof

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Consider a normal operation assigning $t_\alpha$ to each ordinal number $\alpha$, and assume that $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal.

Show that cf $t_\lambda$ $=$ cf $\lambda$.

I want to show that the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\lambda$ is the supremum of $\kappa$ smaller cardinals is equal to the cofinality of the operation. Help would be appreciated here. I know the cofinality of any ordinal $\alpha$ is the least cardinal number $\kappa$ such that there exists a subset $S$ of the ordinal $\alpha$ having cardinality $\kappa$ and that $\alpha$ is the least ordinal $\textit{strictly}$ greater than every member of $S$ (the strict supremum of $S$).

Comment: What is meant by "normal operation"? What is the relationship between $\lambda$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: Normal operation means the operation is both monotone and continuous and what do you mean the relationship between them?

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I meant to write $cf t_{\lambda}$.

Comment: Okay. Well as a starting hint, you need to show both that the left-hand-side is $\leq$ the right-hand side, and that the right-hand-side is $\leq$ the left-hand-side. Which one seems easier to start with?

Comment: The left hand side, I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch:

Pick a cofinal subset $S \subseteq \lambda$. Then
$$
T = \{ t_s \mid s \in S \}
$$
is cofinal in $t_\lambda$. This shows that $\mathrm{cf}(t_\lambda) \le \mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$.

Conversely, let $T \subseteq t_\lambda$ be cofinal. Then
$$
S = \{ \alpha \mid t_\alpha \in T \}
$$
is cofinal in $\lambda$. Hence $\mathrm{cf}(\lambda) \le \mathrm{cf}(t_\lambda)$.

Comment: This is not as much as a hint as it is an outline of a solution.

Comment: This was very helpful, Stefan. Thank you. The proof looks to be much shorter than I thought it would be!

Comment: @Stefan Perhaps you could help me? For the second inequality, how are we sure that $S$ is not empty? $T$ is just a set of ordinals smaller than $t_{\lambda}$, and not all of them are necessarily equal to $t_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in \lambda$. Could we not feasibly have such a set $T$ with none of its elements equal to $t_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in \lambda$?